# Prove by induction that $n^{+}+m=n+m^{+}$ for all $m,n \in \omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just to make sure we use same symbols: $\omega= \mathbb{N}_{0}$, $n^{+}$ is successor of number $n$.
And we define addition by recursion: 
 
$+:\omega \times \omega \rightarrow\omega$ 

$m+0=m$

$m+n^+=(m+n)^+$

I'm trying to prove: $n^++m=n+m^+$ by induction.

Proof:

Let $m \in \omega$ be fixed and $S=\{n\in \omega| n^++m=n+m^+\}$.

Base: $0\in S$ (proof by induction)

Let $S'=\{m\in \omega| 0^++m=0+m^+\}$ (now I'm using this fixed $m$ as variable in induction (not sure if that's ok?))

$0 \in S$ because  $0^++0=0^+=1$ and $0+0^+=(0+0)^+=0^+=1$

 Let $m\in S$ which means $0^++m=0+m^+$.

 Then $0^++m^+=(0^++m)^+=(0+m^+)^+=0+(m^{+})^{+}$. So, $S'=\omega.$

We proved: $0\in S$.

Hypothesis: $n \in S$ which means  $n^++m=n+m^+$

And now I'm stuck. I don't know how to prove step of induction, and I'm not even sure that begining where I start with fixed $m$ is wnough to prove that statement is true for all $m \in \omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will prove by induction that the following holds for all $m \in \omega$: 
$$n^+ + m = n + m^+ \text{ for all }n \in \omega. \tag{1}$$

- For the base case $m = 0$, we just need to show that $n^+ + 0 = n + 0^+$ for all $n \in \omega$.  Note that given any $n \in \omega$ we have
  $$\begin{align} n + 0^+ 
  &= ( n + 0)^+ &\text{(definition of addition)} \\ 
  &= n^+ &\text{(definition of addition by }0\text{)} \\ 
  &= n^+ + 0 &\text{(definition of addition by }0\text{)} \end{align}$$
- For the induction step suppose that $m \in \omega$ is such that (1) holds.  We now want to show that (1) holds for $m^+$, that is
  $$n^+ + m^+ = n + (m^+)^+ \text{ for all }n \in \omega.$$

  Given any $n \in \omega$ we then have that
  $$\begin{align}
  n^+ + m^+ 
  &= ( n^+ + m )^+ &\text{(definition of addition)} \\
  &= ( n + m^+ )^+ &\text{((1) for }m\text{)}\\
  &= n + (m^+)^+ &\text{(definition of addition)}
  \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems that problem is beacuse I tried to prove by n and it's  much easier with m =D. You helped a lot.

Comment: @Mare: You're welcome! If you notice that the recursive definition of addition relies more on the second argument than the first, this should be a clue that inductive arguments should be made on the second argument (at least until you know that $n+m = m+n$ :-) ).

Comment: This was just part of proof that $n+m=m+n$ =)

Answer (score 1):

You started with the wrong $S$ and you inducted on the wrong variable.
Since the induction is done of the second argument of $+$ you need to induct on $m$.
So if you want to prove $\forall n \forall m. m+n^+ = (m+n)^+$, you have to pick $S = \{m / \forall n. n^+ + m = n + m^+\}$

Comment: Do I still have another induction in base and step since I must prove that it is true for every m?

Comment: @Mare : here I don't think so. But in general you may have to use nested inductions yes.